# Could we ever hope to integrate all functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, set-theory, axioms, descriptive-set-theory

The Riemann integral has a weakness, in that it cannot integrate many functions of interest, such as Dirichlet's function $\boldsymbol{1}_\mathbb{Q}$. The Lebesgue and Henstock-Kurzweil integrals extend the range of functions which can be integrated, but still, there are functions which these integrals cannot deal with.

My question is thus. Let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ be a "rich enough" family of "nice enough" subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $\mathcal{A}$ could be the collection of all (bounded?) Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$). Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}$ be the extended real line.

Is it possible to define an "integration functional" $\mathbf{I}: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} \times \mathcal{A} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ satisfying the following:

- $\mathbf{I}$ is total (i.e. it gives a value for every function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and set $B \in \mathcal{A}$);
- $\mathbf{I}$ has the familiar "nice" properties we expect of integrals, e.g.:

  - *Linearity:* $\mathbf{I}(cf+dg,B) = c\mathbf{I}(f,B) + d\mathbf{I}(g,B)$;
  - *Monotonicity:* if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in B$, then $\mathbf{I}(f,B) \leq \mathbf{I}(g,B)$;
  - *Translation invariance:* if $f_c$ is defined by $f_c(x) = f(x+c)$, then $\mathbf{I}(f,B) = \mathbf{I}(f_c,B+c)$;
  - If $B,C \in \mathcal{A}$ are disjoint, then $\mathbf{I}(f,B \cup C) = \mathbf{I}(f,B) + \mathbf{I}(f,C)$;
  - Perhaps there are other properties we might want that I've overlooked.
- Whenever $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is (Riemann/Lebesgue/HK/etc)-integrable on $B$, we have $\mathbf{I}(f,B) = \int_B f$.

In other words, is it *possible* to define a notion of integration which extends standard integration, and can integrate any function? Ideally, we would want $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, but I recognise that we might have to restrict it to get a meaningful/nontrivial answer.

My bet is that the answer will be much the same as Vitali's theorem. I'm guessing that over $\mathsf{ZF}$, $\mathsf{AC}$ would prove there is no such $\mathbf{I}$, while other "nice" axioms such as $\mathsf{AD}$ might allow one to construct such an $\mathbf{I}$.

Comment: Functions that cannot even be integrated in the Lebesgue-sense , are very pathological, and only interesting for a ZFC-purist. If we allow every function, we also have to deal with the problem of the computability. The problem will only have a solution, if we restrict the function somehow.

Comment: Certainly they are pathological. I'm mainly wondering if such a notion could possibly exist, rather than wanting a concrete construction. I expect that AC can prove a contradiction from the existence of such an $\mathbf{I}$ (c.f. the proof of Vitali's theorem).

Comment: I think considering subsets is unnecessary, as we may have $I(f,A)=I(f\cdot \chi_A,\mathbb{R})$ (though it may need to add a more condition.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modulo the problem of assigning a value to "$\infty -\infty$" that can come up in the linearity property, such an object exists (assuming choice). [Note that this is a problem for the Lebesgue integral as well, so you can expect linearity only if at least one of the functions has a finite "integral"]

It is wellknown that there is a finitely (but not countably) additive measure $\mu:\mathcal P(\mathbb R)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ extending the Lebesgue measure that is still translation invariant [cf. [this Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263046/extending-the-lebesgue-measure)]. The point is that one can construct such an $I$ that you are looking for from $\mu$ similar to how one consturcts the Lebesgue integral from the Lebegue measure. We must be careful that this goes through without $\sigma$-additivity.

I will make use of the suggestion of Hanuel Jeon and define a map $I:{}^{\mathbb R}\mathbb R\rightarrow \bar{\mathbb R}$ which satisfies the obvious modification of the properties you are looking for. One can translate $I$ to the setting in the post by defining $I^\prime(f, B)=I(f\cdot\chi_B)$.

As for the Lebesgue integral we start with simple functions. We call a function $f$ simple if it is of the form 
$$f=\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\chi_{A_i}$$
Where $A_i\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ and $\alpha_i\geq 0$ for all $i<n$. For such $f$ we set $I(f)=\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\mu(A_i)$. Now more generally for positive functions $g\geq 0$ we let 
$$I(g)=\operatorname{sup}\{I(f)\mid f\leq g\text{ is simple}\}$$
It is easy to check (using the monotonicity of $\mu$) that this definition agrees with the earlier one for simple functions $g$.

It is clear that, up to now, $I$ is monotonic and translation invariant (as $\mu$ is). First lets check that $I$ agrees with the Lebesgue integral for a Lebesgue measurable positive function $g$. Clearly $\int g\ d\lambda\leq I(g)$ since any Lebegue measurable simple function is simple. To show $\geq$, let $f\leq g$ be simple. Write 
$$f=\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\chi_{A_i}$$

Now we have 
$$I(f)=\sum_{i<n} \alpha_i\mu(A_i)\leq\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\mu(\{g\geq\alpha_i\})=\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\lambda(\{g\geq\alpha_i\})\leq\int g\ d\lambda$$

which is what we needed to show.

Linearity holds true as well, but is a little awkward to show. It is easy to see that $I(c g)=cI(g)$ for any positive $g$ and $c\geq 0$. Suppose we have two positive $g, h$. We have $I(g)+I(h)\leq I(g+h)$ since for any $g_0\leq g, h_0\leq h$ simple, $g_0+h_0\leq g+h$ is simple and $I(g_0+h_0)= I(g_0)+I(h_0)$ (which can be easily checked). To show $\geq$, given $f\leq g+h$ simple and $\epsilon>0$, we will produce simple $g_0\leq g$, $h_0\leq h$ such that $f\leq g_0+h_0+\epsilon$. (This suffices). Let $\alpha_\ast=\operatorname{max}(f)$

There is then a simple $g_0\leq g$ such that

- $g(x)-g_0(x)<\epsilon$ if $g(x)<\alpha_\ast$
- $g_0(x)=\alpha_\ast$ if $g(x)\geq\alpha_\ast$

Such a $g_0$ is not difficult to construct. If we let $h_0=\operatorname{max}\{f-g_0-\epsilon, 0\}$ then $h_0$ is simple and $h_0\leq h$. Thus $g_0, h_0$ are as desired.

Finally we can define $I(f)=I(f^+)-I(f^-)$ for a general $f$ if at least one of $I(f^+), I(f^-)$ is finite, where $f^+=\operatorname{max}\{f, 0\}$ and $f^-=\operatorname{max}\{-f, 0\}$. All the nice properties we care about are preserved in this step.

$I$ has many strange properties. For example there is an everywhere positive function $g$ with $I(g)=0$. Furthermore, for the Lebegue integral it is the case that if $g$ is Lebesgue measurable and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and converges to $g$ pointwise and all $f_n$ are Lebesgue simple, then $\int g\ d\lambda=\operatorname{sup}_{n\in\mathbb N} I(f_n)$. This is no longer true in our setting: $I(g)$ can be infinite while there is an increasing sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of simple functions converging to $g$ pointwise with $I(f_n)=0$ for all $n$. Luckily we did not need this.

A final remark: You mentioned AD in the post. Under AD, all sets of reals and thus all functions $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ are Lebesgue measurable. Hence the Lebesgue integral itself is such an example.

Edit: As requested, here are some examples of functions with these "strange properties" described above. Using the Vitali set construction, we can find a partition $\langle A_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\rangle$ of $[0, 1]$ so that the $A_i's$ are translations of each other modulo the equivalence relation $x\cong y\Leftrightarrow x-y\in\mathbb Z$. Since $\mu$ is translation invariant, they must all have the same measure and as they partition a set of finite measure, they are of measure $0$. Now let $B_i=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb Z} A_i+j$. Then the function 
$$g=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i}\chi_{B_i}$$
is positive everywhere as the $B_i$ partition $\mathbb R$. However, if $A$ is a set with finite $\mu$-measure and $A\subseteq\{g\geq\alpha\}$ for some $\alpha>0$ then $\mu(A)=0$. If follows that for any simple $f\leq g$ we have $I(f)=0$ and thus $I(g)=0$.

For the second strange property, take the $A_i$ from above again and a bijection $h:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. Let
$$f_n=\sum_{i<n}\chi_{A_{h(i)_0}+h(i)_1}$$
Then all $f_n$ are simple with $I(f_n)=0$ and the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and converges pointwise to $g$ the constant function with value 1.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference, or a standard name for this construction? It would help the interested learn more by giving an easily google-able phrase

Comment: Nice solution. Can you give witnesses for the "strange properties" you mentioned, i.e. what would be examples of such $g$ or $f_n$? And I wonder what properties would be needed to get a negative result like Vitali's theorem. I was thinking that one may be able to derive a contradiction in a similar way by requiring monotone convergence (which seems a reasonable enough property to have...)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I dont know if this construction has a name, but it should appear in any standard text with an introduction to measure theory

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett Thanks! I have given some examples in an edit. I suppose any reasonable "convergence property" for $I$ would require $\mu$ to be countably additive, which is incompatible with translation invariance by Vitali's theorem.

Comment: @AndreasLietz I meant in particular a name for the integral you get when you use a finitely additive measure, akin to lebesgue integral when you do this construction with the lebesgue measure, or haar integration when you do it with the haar measure. Sorry for the confusion